# openNLP NGramModel does not keep the original order of the words?

Tags: opennlp

Here is my simple code using openNLP:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String text = "This is the original sequence in the text";
    System.out.println(text);

    StringList tokens = new StringList(WhitespaceTokenizer.INSTANCE.tokenize(text));
    System.out.println("Tokens: " + tokens);

    NGramModel nGramModel = new NGramModel();
    nGramModel.add(tokens, 2, 2);

    System.out.println("Total ngrams: " + nGramModel.numberOfGrams());
    for (StringList ngram : nGramModel) {
        System.out.println(nGramModel.getCount(ngram) + " - " + ngram);
    }

}
```

and it gives the following output:

```
 This is the original sequence in the text
 Tokens: [This,is,the,original,sequence,in,the,text]
 Total ngrams: 7
 1 - [the,text]
 1 - [the,original]
 1 - [is,the]
 1 - [sequence,in]
 1 - [This,is]
 1 - [original,sequence]
 1 - [in,the]
```

So it does *not* keep the original order of the words in the sentence? How can I get `[This,is]` as the very first n-gram, and then `[is,the]` as the second ngram, ... so on so forth? if we lose this original ordering of the n-gram... would that hurt?

thanks for the help!

Comment: if the word order is important, maybe an ngram model is not what you want.  The ngram model is based on markov chain theory, which means that only the current state (not the history of states) is important.  see chapter 4 of Jurafsky's s&L text: (Thank you Stanford NLP and Dan Jurafsky for making this available)  https://web.stanford.edu/~jurafsky/slp3/4.pdf

Answer (score 3):

I think it's important to clarify what is your use case and why you think you need order preserved.
Ngrams are often used in bag of words models (which disrespect order anyway) and / or in language models where probability estimation (e.g. based on ngram counts) are calculated at ngram level and aggregated using the chain rule.

Comment: thanks for explaining, that makes sense. A follow-up thing: is there a model in openNLP that actually can keep the ordering and also generate n-grams?